# java list of jframe components

Tags: java, jframe

Hello Im working with jframe (in java) and I wonder if there is some sort of list for all the jframe Components.

What I mean with Components: jbutton, jtextarea, jcombobox and stuff like that

Comment: [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JFrame#getComponents`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents()) that is inherited from `Container`

> Gets all the components in this container.
>
> Note: This method should be
>   called under AWT tree lock. Returns: an array of all the components in
>   this container. See also: Component.getTreeLock()

### Example

```
Component[] frameCompos = myFrame.getComponents();
// How to print it?
// 1
for (Component c : frameCompos) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
// 2
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(frameCompos));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do I display it? System.out.println(frameCompos) just prints: [Ljava.awt.Component;@52d455b8

Comment: @MCrafterzz Edited it.